# How to use sem_destroy safely?

Tags: c, posix, semaphore

I use POSIX `unnamed semaphore` in my code. And I want to use `sem_destroy` to destroy semaphore. But I read [Linux manual page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sem_destroy.3.html). It say "**Destroying a semaphore that other processes or threads are currently blocked on (in sem_wait(3)) produces undefined behavior.**".

My question is:
How can I safely use sem_destroy (Avoid calling sem_destroy when other threads or processes are blocked on)

Comment: You wrote your code, so you're responsible for knowing once it's done using the semaphore.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I safely use sem_destroy (Avoid calling sem_destroy when other threads or processes are blocked on)

You're probably better off *not*.  An unnamed semaphore will be cleaned up automatically when no processes remain that could access it.

But if you insist, then you need to recognize that the only safe time to destroy a synchronization object such as a semaphore is when every thread of every process that has access to it has *finished* with it.  Most frequently, you know that this is the case because the current thread is the only one left alive that has access to the semaphore.  With sufficient knowledge of the behavior of the various threads and processes involved, you might be able to know sooner, or even to engineer the correct circumstances.

Comment: Thank you! May I ask which article this sentence "An unnamed semaphore will be cleaned up automatically when no processes remain that could access it." appears in? I did not see it in the Linux manual page.

Comment: If I use unnamed semaphore in shared memory of multiple processes. I don't use sem_destroy. Will the unnamed semaphore be cleaned up automatically?